# How to restrict a Django model to a single one-to-one relation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I am currently building a Django app that requires two different user types and I know that storing authentication information across multiple models/tables is a bad idea.

As such, I have created a **User** model to handle the authentication information (username, password, etc.). I have then created two different models, one for the buyers and one for the sellers, each with their own unique fields and one-to-one relationship to the **User** model.

Now, I thought this would work, but the problem is that it is still possible for a different buyer and seller to have the same **User** relation. How can I prevent this and restrict the **User** model to only a single one-to-one relation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to achieve your goal like this:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    """An abstract base class for Buyer and Seller"""
    
    # We define an id file in the abstract class
    # this way the id is unique for Buyer and Seller
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Buyer(Actor):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('id', 'user_id',)

class Seller(Actor):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('id', 'user_id',)
```

With this example, one Buyer is linked to only one user and one Seller is linked to only one user too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would only work if the Buyer and Seller models always have the same ID increment value.

Comment: I updated the answer with abstract class for Buyer and Seller

Answer (score 0):

you can add role in actor's model and make a pre_save signal before save user in buyer or seller model

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31703354)